# What is the concept of Service Affinity in OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

**Situation**

When a deployment fails on our OpenShift 3.11 instance because of a `Failed Scheduling` error event, a message comparable to the following shown:

> Failed Scheduling 0/11 nodes are available: 10 CheckServiceAffinity, 2 ExistingPodsAntiAffinityRulesNotMatch, 2 MatchInterPodAffinity, 5 MatchNodeSelector.

In the above error message, the term `CheckServiceAffinity` is used. While it's easy to find articles on Pod Affinity or Anti-Affinity, I couldn't find a detailed description of Service Affinity.

**Question**

1. What is Service Affinity?
2. Is it a concept of Kubernetes or is it exclusive to OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ServiceAffinity places pods on nodes based on the service running on that pod. Placing pods of the same service on the same or co-located nodes can lead to higher efficiency.
2. It's a concept of openshift and not of open source kubernetes.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/scheduling/scheduler.html#configurable-predicates